# How do I PSRemote start procdump such that it persists after the session ends

Tags: powershell-remoting

I can start a persistent process on unix with:

```
nohup process &
```

It will continue to run after I close my bash session. I cannot seem to do the same with PowerShell remoting on Windows. I can open a PSRemote session with a server and start a process, but as soon as I close that session it dies. My assumption is this is a benefit of strong sandboxing, but it's a benefit I'd rather work around somehow. Any ideas?

So far I've tried:

```
$exe ='d:\procdump.exe'
$processArgs = '-ma -e -t -n 3 -accepteula w3wp.exe d:\Dumps'
1) [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($exe,$processArgs)
2) Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($exe,$processArgs) [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($exe,$processArgs)} -ArgumentList ($exe,$processArgs)
3) start powershell {param($exe ='d:\procdump.exe', $processArgs = '-ma -e -t -n 3 -accepteula w3wp.exe d:\Dumps') [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($exe,$processArgs)}
4) start powershell {param($exe ='d:\procdump.exe', $processArgs = '-ma -e -t -n 3 -accepteula w3wp.exe d:\Dumps') Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($exe,$processArgs) [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($exe,$processArgs)} -ArgumentList ($exe,$processArgs)}
```

The program runs up until I close the session, then the procdump is reaped. The coolest thing about procdump is it will self-terminate, and I'd like to leave it running to take advantage of that fact.

I'd been starting ADPlus remotely, holding a session open, and just terminating the session to kill the captures. That's kind of handy, but it requires an awful lot of polling, inspecting, and deciding when is the right moment to kill the capture process before filling up the hard drive but after capturing enough dumps to be useful. I can leave procdump running indefinitely while it waits for an appropriate trigger and when it's captured enough data it will just die. That's lovely.

I just need to get procdump to keep running after I terminate my remote session. It's probably not worth creating a procdump scheduled task and starting it, but that's about the last idea I've got left.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not directly possible. Indirectly, yes a task or a service could be created and started remotely, but simply pushing a process off into the SYSTEM space is not.

I resolved my issue by spawning a local job to start the remote job and remain alive for the required period of time. The local job holds the remote session open then dies at the appropriate time, and the parent local process is able to continue to run uninterrupted and harvest the return value of the remote procdump with ReceiveJob if I happen to care.